# How to find all connected subgraph of a graph in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm developing a python application, and i want to list all possible connected subgraph of any size and starting from every node using NetworkX.

I just tried using combinations() from itertools library to find all possible combination of nodes but it is very too slow because it searchs also for not connected nodes:

```
for r in range(0,NumberOfNodes)
for SG in (G.subgraph(s) for s in combinations(G,r):
    if (nx.is_connected(SG)):
        nx.draw(SG,with_labels=True)
        plt.show()
```

The actual output is correct. But i need another way faster to do this, because all combinations of nodes with a graph of 50 nodes and 8 as LenghtTupleToFind are up to 1 billion (n! / r! / (n-r)!) but only a minimal part of them are connected subgraph so are what i am interested in. So, it's possible to have a function for do this?

Sorry for my english, thank you in advance

**EDIT**:

As an example:

[image: example of starting graph]

so, the results i would like to have:

```
[0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
[0,1,4]
[0,2,5]
[0,2,5,4]
[0,1,4,5]
[0,1,2,4,5]
[0,1,2,3]
[0,1,2,3,5]
[0,1,2,3,4]
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[0,3,2]
[0,3,1]
[0,3,2]
[0,1,4,2]
```

and all combination that generates a connected graph

Comment: Do you want something like [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))?

Comment: yes, but of any size. so if node with id = 0 is connected with nodes with id 1 and 2 and node with id = 1 is connected with another node with id 3. i Want something like this:
[0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,1,3,2]

Comment: Why not [0, 3] ?

Comment: because 0 is not directly connected with 3, there is 1 in the middle

Comment: Are you looking for all the possible --fully-connected-- sub-graphs? Maybe it would be helpful for understanding what you are looking for to include a drawing of a small example graph (see [mcve]). Also, what is the `combinations()` function?

Comment: i have edited the answer, i hope it will be helpful.  the combinations() function is a function that returns all possible combinations of a given array. es: array: "ASDF" 
Combinations(Array,2) = AS AD AF SD SF DF
it is in itertools

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirements  and ended up using this code, super close to what you were doing. This code yields exactly the input you asked for.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = you_graph
all_connected_subgraphs = []

# here we ask for all connected subgraphs that have at least 2 nodes AND have less nodes than the input graph
for nb_nodes in range(2, G.number_of_nodes()):
    for SG in (G.subgraph(selected_nodes) for selected_nodes in itertools.combinations(G, nb_nodes)):
        if nx.is_connected(SG):
            print(SG.nodes)
            all_connected_subgraphs.append(SG)
```

Comment: It does what it should but it is not usable for even middle-sized graphs because of the runtime

Comment: Good point ... At the time I could not find anything better though, and it's possible this is a NP-complex problem

Answer (score 1):

The following function performs the task efficiently:

```py
def get_all_connected_subgraphs(G):
    """Get all connected subgraphs by a recursive procedure"""

    con_comp = [c for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)]

    def recursive_local_expand(node_set, possible, excluded, results, max_size):
        """
        Recursive function to add an extra node to the subgraph being formed
        """
        results.append(node_set)
        if len(node_set) == max_size:
            return
        for j in possible - excluded:
            new_node_set = node_set | {j}
            excluded = excluded | {j}
            new_possible = (possible | set(G.neighbors(j))) - excluded
            recursive_local_expand(new_node_set, new_possible, excluded, results, max_size)
   
    results = []
    for cc in con_comp:
        max_size = len(cc)

        excluded = set()
        for i in G:
            excluded.add(i)
            recursive_local_expand({i}, set(G.neighbors(i)) - excluded, excluded, results, max_size)

    results.sort(key=len)

    return results
```

Tested with your graph:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (2, 5), (5,4), (4,1)]
G = nx.Graph(e)
# nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
# plt.show()

results = get_all_connected_subgraphs(G)
for el in results:
    print(el)
```

It returns:

```
{0}
{1}
{2}
{3}
{5}
{4}
{0, 1}
{0, 2}
{0, 3}
{1, 4}
{2, 5}
{4, 5}
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 3}
{0, 1, 4}
{0, 2, 3}
{0, 2, 5}
{1, 4, 5}
{2, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 3}
{0, 1, 2, 4}
{0, 1, 2, 5}
{0, 1, 3, 4}
{0, 1, 4, 5}
{0, 2, 3, 5}
{0, 2, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5}
{0, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

BTW, the example solution provided in the question is missing several subgraphs.

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751315/12842085) to design the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Charly Empereur-mot's answer by using ego graph to make it faster:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = you_graph.copy()
all_connected_subgraphs = []

# here we ask for all connected subgraphs that have nb_nodes
for n in you_graph.nodes():
    egoG = nx.generators.ego_graph(G,n,radius=nb_nodes-1)
    for SG in (G.subgraph(sn+(n,) for sn in itertools.combinations(egoG, nb_nodes-1)):
        if nx.is_connected(SG):
            all_connected_subgraphs.append(SG)
    G.remove_node(n)
```

Comment: I would like to understand your code snippet but I have problems to figure out where `nb_nodes` comes from or whether `nb_nodes` and `n` are the same. Can it be applied to graphs in general?

Comment: The code is wrong. A working code (based on this example) can be found  at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75727217/12842085

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [connected_components](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) function. It will return you all connected nodes, which you can then filter by size and node.

Answer (score -1):

You can find all the connected components in O(n) time and memory complexity. Keep a seen boolean array, and run Depth First Search (DFS) or Bread First Search (BFS), to find the connected components.
In my code, I used DFS to find the connected components.

```
seen = [False] * num_nodes
def search(node):
    component.append(node)
    seen[node] = True
    for neigh in G.neighbors(node):
        if not seen[neigh]:
            dfs(neigh)

all_subgraphs = []    

# Assuming nodes are numbered 0, 1, ..., num_nodes - 1
for node in range(num_nodes):
    component = []
    dfs(node)
    # Here `component` contains nodes in a connected component of G
    plot_graph(component)  # or do anything
    all_subgraphs.append(component)
```

Comment: i can't understand the first line, please can you explain?

Comment: An array of size num_nodes initialized to False

Comment: @DarioBranco seen is list of size num_nodes initialized to False. It tells whether we have seen/visited this node before or not.

Comment: and it is in the function? i see it is outside