# Networkx 2.4: Finding ALL Cliques

Tags: python, networkx

I created a graph, with Networkx 2.4, with the following edges:

```
EdgeView([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7)])
```

When I request all cliques using `networx.enumerate_all_cliques(G)`, the maximum clique has only four vertices, e.g. `[2,3,5,7]`.
How do I list cliques with more than 4 vertices, e.g. `[0,1,2,3,5,6]` or, some other way to get all possible subgraphs from 1 to n nodes.

Comment: [0,1,2,3,5,6] is not a clique, for example there is no edge (0,6). If you just need to enumerate all possible connected induced subgraphs, you shouldn't use `enumerate_all_cliques`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all connected subgraph of a graph in networkx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440779/how-to-find-all-connected-subgraph-of-a-graph-in-networkx)

Comment: Thanks Grismar, I think it does. I will give  "How to find all connected subgraph of a graph in networkx" a try.

Comment: You're not getting cliques with more that 4 nodes because there aren't any. The largest has exactly 4 nodes. Note that a clique is a *complete subgraph* within your graph.  [0,1,2,3,5,6] is not complete