# Fast way to find all connected subgraphs of given size in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

*[Note: A fast solution was given in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751315/12842085) however further improvement concerning speed is desirable.]*

Given is an undirected sparsely connected graph *G* with *n* vertices. I am looking for a fast way to find all connected subgraphs of *G* with *m* vertices. It can be assumed that *m* ≪ *n* and that the degree of the vertices of *G* is *deg(v)*≪*n*.

**Graphical example**

For the example we have *n*=5, *m*=3.

The 4 connected subgraphs are: (0,1,2),(1,2,3),(0,2,3),(2,3,4)

[image]

**Code example**

Following code using `networkx` and `ego_graph` is quite slow. It takes about 100 seconds for a graph with *n*=100, *deg(v)*=10, *m*=4. It is an example for *m* ≪ *n* and *deg(v)*≪*n*. The case *n*=10000 would take eternal time.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
import time

n=100   #nodes in graph
deg=10  #node degree in graph
m=4     #nodes in subgraph

graph=nx.gnm_random_graph(n,n*deg,seed=1)#construct random graph

starttime=time.time()
G = graph.copy()
all_connected_subgraphs = []
radius=m-1
for n in graph.nodes():
    egoG = nx.ego_graph(G,n,radius=radius,center=False)# all closeby nodes
    for sn in itertools.combinations(egoG, radius):# test all combinations of closeby nodes
        SG=[n,*sn]
        G_sub=G.subgraph(SG)
        if nx.is_connected(G_sub):
            all_connected_subgraphs.append(SG)
    G.remove_node(n)

endtime=time.time()
print(endtime-starttime)
```

The slow steps are the lines `G_sub=G.subgraph(SG)` and `if nx.is_connected(G_sub):` that consume 20% and 80% of total calculation time, respectively.

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54440779/12842085) no efficient solution was given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using a recursive generator function: I didn't use NetworkX, so instead the graph is represented as a list of sets of neighbours.

```py
def all_connected_subgraphs(g, m):
    def _recurse(t, possible, excluded):
        if len(t) == m:
            yield t
        else:
            excluded = set(excluded)
            for i in possible:
                if i not in excluded:
                    new_t = (*t, i)
                    new_possible = possible | g[i]
                    excluded.add(i)
                    yield from _recurse(new_t, new_possible, excluded)
    excluded = set()
    for (i, possible) in enumerate(g):
        excluded.add(i)
        yield from _recurse((i,), possible, excluded)
```

It's a backtracking algorithm which says, given a partial subgraph of size `< m` and a set of nodes that are allowed to be added, add each node and expand the set of possible options to include all nodes reachable from that node. To reduce symmetry, we keep track of which nodes have already been used and add these to the `excluded` set.

Demonstration using your example graph:

```py
>>> example_graph = [{1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3}]
>>> list(all_connected_subgraphs(example_graph, 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Here's the code I used to generate a random graph, which should be equivalent to the G(n, m) distribution you're sampling from:

```py
import random
import itertools as it

def random_graph(n, num_edges):
    adj_sets = [set() for i in range(n)]
    all_edges = list(it.combinations(range(n), 2))
    random.shuffle(all_edges)
    for (i, j) in all_edges[:num_edges]:
        adj_sets[i].add(j)
        adj_sets[j].add(i)
    return adj_sets
```

The running time on my laptop is under half a second to find all connected subgraphs of size 4 from a graph with 100 nodes and 1,000 edges, like your benchmark:

```py
>>> g = random_graph(100, 1000)
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: list(all_connected_subgraphs(g, 4)), number=1)
0.42606337900360813
```

Note that `list` is needed here to exhaust the generator, otherwise the algorithm won't actually generate any subgraphs. If you just want to iterate over all connected subgraphs with a `for` loop then you don't need to put them in a list first.

There are various "easy" ways to optimise this, e.g. the set of edges for each node `i` can be filtered first to remove "back-edges" to nodes less than `i`, and the recursion could be replaced with a stack to make an iterative algorithm that doesn't use `yield` (which can have a relatively large performance overhead). But those optimisations are probably not needed unless your inputs need to be considerably bigger or denser.

Comment: @granularbastard What do you actually want to do with all of the connected subgraphs once you have found them? If it's anything non-trivial then the sheer number of them will be of more concern than the rate at which you can generate them. If e.g. you just want to count them then there are surely smarter things you can do that don't require generating them all. Still, empirical tests suggest you should be able to scale this algorithm up to 50,000 nodes if you don't mind waiting on the order of 15-30 minutes for the result.

Comment: @granularbastard What *do* you want to do with them? If n=20,000, deg=10 and m=4, you're looking at somewhere on the order of 50,000,000 subgraphs, so if you have hundreds of graphs then you're talking about billions of subgraphs. Even if the thing you are doing with each subgraph takes only 1 millisecond, you're still talking about several months solid of computation time, even if actually generating the subgraphs takes zero time. So you had better be doing something fairly simple, and then there is probably a better option than brute force.

Comment: @granularbastard Yes, it can be, as I said in the last paragraph of my answer. However, the speed you are consuming them is going to be a bigger concern than the speed you are generating them. So again, what do you want to do with them? Squeezing the maximum possible speed out of a brute force search is rarely a sensible approach to a problem.

Comment: @kay3 The algorithm fails for many cases. The simplest case where it fails is [{2}, {2}, {0, 1}] and m=3. But for the same graph [{1}, {0,2}, {1}] (just different labeling) the component is found.

Comment: @granularbastard Thank you, there was a mistake in the symmetry reduction logic. This meant the algorithm was considering fewer options than were necessary, and that also caused an underestimate of the running time. I've edited to fix this issue, and updated the time estimate.

Comment: @kay3 Thanks. Although I do not understand your code it works.