# Find all possible complementary combinations of subgraphs within a graph

Tags: python, graph, combinations, networkx, combinatorics

Suppose I have a graph, in my case I have created it using `networkx` as followed:

```
import networkx as nx
Graph = nx.Graph()
nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
Graph.add_nodes_from(nodes)
Graph.edges = ((5, 1),(5, 2),(1, 2),(1, 8),(15, 14),(8, 12),(8, 10),(8, 9),(12, 13),(9, 14),(9, 11),(2, 10),(4, 7),(4, 6),(4, 3),(4, 12),(7, 8),(13, 15),(6, 12),(6, 7),(3, 7),(3, 5),(3, 1),(11, 10))
```

I can group several nodes into a subgraph, when the nodes are connected.

I want to find all the possible ways of splitting the graph into up-to 4 subgraphs.

So far, I've found all the possible group of nodes using this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873085/13771970 :

```
def get_all_connected_subgraphs(G):
    """Get all connected subgraphs by a recursive procedure"""

    con_comp = [c for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)]

    def recursive_local_expand(node_set, possible, excluded, results, max_size):
        """
        Recursive function to add an extra node to the subgraph being formed
        """
        results.append(node_set)
        # results = sorted(results)
        if len(node_set) == max_size:
            return
        for j in possible - excluded:
            new_node_set = node_set | {j}
            excluded = excluded | {j}
            new_possible = (possible | set(G.neighbors(j))) - excluded
            recursive_local_expand(new_node_set, new_possible, excluded, results, max_size)

    results = []
    for cc in con_comp:
        max_size = len(cc)

        excluded = set()
        for i in G:
            excluded.add(i)
            recursive_local_expand({i}, set(G.neighbors(i)) - excluded, excluded, results, max_size)

    results.sort(key=len)

    return results
```

Then I can simply find all possible subgraphs by calling `subpgraphs = get_all_connected_subgraphs(Graph)`

Nevertheless, now I want to find all possible ways of splitting the Graph into maximum 4 subgraphs (i.e., all combinations of 2, 3 and 4 subgraphs).

Something like this:

```
[
(1, 5, 36, 690), # Each value is the index of a single subgraph
(1, 4, 85, 2358),
...
]
```

I appreciate your help in advance. Thank you!

Comment: "I call them supernodes"  Why not call them by the standard terminology, which is cliques.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_graph.  Using this term and google, you will find lots of algorithms.

Comment: https://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/jchoco/clique/enumeration/papers/bronKerbosch.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I changed the name. But I still don't find an algorithm to get all possible combination of Cliques

Comment: find_cliques() https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html

Comment: Looking at the `is_connected` function, is does not seem that the objective is to find cliques. Clique is a set of nodes that spans a complete subgraph. Here the subgraph needs to be only connected.

Comment: @bb1 The question is not clear.  " I respect the adjacency (all the nodes must be connected)"  Is it adjacency or is it merely connected?  Nicolás Rivera please clarify your question.

Comment: @bb1 'Adjacency' is mentioned in the title, so my best guess is cliques are wanted.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge in Graph theory. I didn't clarify that the Graph is undirected, with adjacency I meant that all the nodes must be connected.

Comment: Let's help you improve your knowledge.  Look up the meaning, in a graph theory context, of the terms adjacency and reachability, component and clique.  Now work through your question applying the various terms to express what you really mean.  Then the folks that might be able to help with your problem will be able to understand exactly what it is.

Comment: I re-formulated my question, but sadly the post has been forgotten.